# Javascript function called in html not functioning (undefined error)

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

Although I have saved this javascript script in my root folder along with my html pages I am continuously getting the undefined error. I believe I have formatted the onclick event correctly as well as the script header but I have seen some variations and tried a few.

The functionality of this program will eventually be to save the id of the image in a textbox on another html page but until this works I cannot progress further.

Thank you for your suggestions

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../getstring.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="blankpage.html">
      <img title="returns true if the Channel is marked as active, or false if not " id=".Active"  onclick="getstring();"
      src="Images/Diagram/ChannelDropMembers/Active.jpg" alt="Active" style="width:120px;height:60px;">

    <a href="blankpage.html">
      <img title="Returns the name of the encapsulated data (Inherited from Drop.)" id=".Name" onclick="getstring();"
      src="Images/Diagram/ChannelDropMembers/Name.jpg" alt="Name" style="width:120px;height:60px;">

    <a href="PeripheralUnitDrop.html">
      <img title="returns a PeripheralUnitDrop that encapsulates the peripheral object owning this channel " id=".Parent" onclick="getstring();"
      src="Images/Diagram/ChannelDropMembers/Parent.jpg" alt="Parent" style="width:120px;height:60px;">

    <a href="blankpage.html">
      <img title="returns a string containing the name of the Channel's parent peripheral device instance, or empty string if the parent is not a driver unit or the driver unit has no peripheral device instance set " id=".ParentInstanceName" onclick="getstring();"
      src="Images/Diagram/ChannelDropMembers/ParentInstanceName.jpg" alt="ParentInstanceName" style="width:120px;height:60px;">

    <a href="blankpage.html">
      <img title="returns a string containing the Plc name alias of the Channel, or NULL if PlcName has not been set " id=".PlcName" onclick="getstring();"
      src="Images/Diagram/ChannelDropMembers/PlcName.jpg" alt="PlcName" style="width:120px;height:60px;">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error you're getting?

Comment: can you add the JS code so we can confirm that? Have you tried in-lining the code to ensure that it is an issue with file pathing?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the way that you have indented that in your question but: those `<a>` tags are not closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JS file is, as you say, in the root folder along with the HTML files, then the path should be `"./getstring.js"`, not `"../getstring.js"`.

Comment: I just tried this but it still is listed as undefined.

Comment: _what_ is undefined? Where is your javascript code? Could you add it to your original question?